# Selecting different counts from the same column with different where conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a such structure:

```
event_name      country
a               us
a               gb
b               us
b               us
c               gb
c               gb
c               au
d               au
d               au
```

I am trying to get in big query:

```
country     a_count     b_count     c_count     d_count
us          1           2           0           0
gb          1           0           2           0
au          0           0           0           2
```

I tried:

```
select geo.country as country, 
sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS `a_count`,  
sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS `b_count `,
sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS `c_count `,
sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS `d_count `
from `table`
group by country;
```

But I get:

> Syntax error: Unexpected ")" at [2:62]

How can I achieve this result in big query?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it tells to return only distinct rows (which are already distinct if all `group by` columns are present in `select` list). So just remove `DISTINCT` and brackets around `country`

Comment: The `case` expressions need `END` and the end.

Comment: Updated the query but I still get the the same error, before the first closing bracket.

Comment: Move the closing bracket to the other side of 'END' ... `sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d_count `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BigQuery you would use `countif()`:

```
select geo.country as country, 
       countif(event_name like 'a') AS a_count,  
       countif(event_name like 'b') AS b_count,
       countif(event_name like 'c') AS c_count,
       countif(event_name like 'd') AS d_count
from `table`
group by country;
```

I suspect your problem is the space at the end of `b_count` .  That said, the syntax error is pretty clear:

> Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

Comment: Thank you, this works, just need to remove `END` from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about bigquery but it seems you have systex error. Edn of case should be inside the bracket. Please try below query:

```
select geo.country as country, 
sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `a_count`,  
sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `b_count `,
sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `c_count `,
sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `d_count `
from `table`
group by country;
```